# Find the smallest set of strings which "covers" a given set of strings (coverage = containing as substring)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, approximation, strings, substrings

Let $S$ be a finite set of strings and $0 < k\leq l$ integers. We want to find the smallest set of strings $T(k,l)$ for which the following holds:

- $\forall t \in T(k,l): k \leq |t| \leq l$
- $\forall s \in S \ \exists t \in T(k,l): t \subset s$ (meaning: $s$ is containing $t$ as a contiguous substring).

I would appreciate any help regarding this problem. I see that I could generate the set of all strings with length between $k$ and $l$ then consider the power set but I think there must be a better way to solve this.

I'm not even sure how hard this problem is (I think there may be a reduction for the set cover problem which means it is $NP$-complete but I really don't know) or if there are any good approximation (or maybe exact) algorithms available.

I would like to solve this problem primarily in practice. Typically, $3 \leq k \leq l \leq 10$ holds, $|S| \approx 2000$ and the lengths of the elements in $S$ can vary from 10 to 50 mainly.

Comment: This problem appears to be a generalization of the longest common substring problem. There is a lot of literature on the related longest common sub _sequence_ problem (which is NP-hard), but I'm having a hard time finding similar results for the substring version. (which I also believe to be hard)

Comment: Surely k doesn't affect the problem in any way: if you can do this with T containing a string of length less than k then you can just pad that string to have length k...

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You mean $l$, right? We are looking for a _sub_ string, so we cannot just pad the elements in T. We can, of course, make them smaller.

Comment: Approximation algs for this problem are discussed in Vijay Vazirani's text on approximation algorithms.   https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=bJmqCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=vijay+vazirani+approximation+algorithms+text&ots=nEr9TVJLkY&sig=1AHTURyFxhBj-yban9v--bUgPR0#v=snippet&q=superstring&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can take $l=k$.  In particular, any solution to $T(k,l)$ can be converted into a solution for $T(k,k)$ by shortening each string that's longer to $k$ to a string of length $k$ (by deleting as many characters from the beginning or end as needed to get down to length $k$, chosen arbitrarily).  So, it will simplify your life to focus on solving $T(k,k)$, i.e., finding a set of strings of length $k$.

Here is one possible approach.  You don't need to exhaustively generate all strings of length $k$.  Instead, you can generate all length-$k$ substrings of words of $S$.  If each word of $S$ has length $\le n$, then there will be $\le (n-k+1) \cdot |S|$ of them.  Then, you could apply some standard set-cover algorithm to that.  So, you don't need to generate exponentially many strings; just polynomially many.

It's possible there may be better algorithms that take into account the combinatorial structure of the strings; I don't know.